# Google Sheets Sums with Unique parameters

Tags: google-sheets

I made this test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evuTnCh4Oq60totOtgtXzjJA41YsSDYQoSuMmTegIhU/edit?usp=sharing
And all I need is to get the unique values with the sum of them in the next row:
in C1  I need to show , potato , tomato (unique values)
in D1 I need to show the sum of them
(20)
(25)

But even using chatGPT I can't find the right code.

Can you guys help me? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(A:B;"Select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''")
```

[image]

***Updated formula***:

```js
=let(Σ; query(hstack(A:A;C:C);"Select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''");
     vstack(Σ; hstack("Total";sum(index(Σ;;2)))))
```

Comment: Worked!! Now i gonna try to use it on the real sheet :D Thank you really much!

Comment: Can i group it without the column? Like, a1 to a4 or b1 to b4, because in the real sheet i'm not going to use the column, i need to set the interval instead

Comment: Sorry I cant get a picture of what you are trying to convey. If you can recreate it in your test sheet; maybe the visual aspect would clear things out...

Comment: Worked, but i need another thing.
I need to skip the "doesnt matter" column and do the same thing but only with the a and c columns. is that possible? 
I updated the test sheet so you can see

Comment: replace `A:B` part in the formula with `hstack(A:A;C:C)`

Comment: "Function QUERY parameter 3 expects number values, but 'Select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'''' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''

Comment: Oh i forgot the hstack, worked!! Could you please breafly explain what did you do in general? so i can understand not only copy and paste

Comment: Last question: Now i need to add the total under the last value.
Like in d3 the Word Total and in e3 the sum of the values above.
But if i add another thing like Apples - 15 , it need to go one cell under and show the word total and the value

Comment: Try the updated formula added to the answer

Comment: Thank you for everything. One more doubt, maybe you can help me, how can i make it work on excel? Just found out those formulas doesn't work there. Do you have any adaptation you can suggest me?

Comment: You could post n' seek help on `excel` tag

Comment: Alright! Thank you for all the help <3 You helped me a lot, thank you!!